# MySQL like reversed

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get around pulling all the data from a table, and cycling through it with php.  Here's my current Query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
ExampleTable
WHERE
StringContains LIKE "%lkjlkjsomeuser@example.comjkjhkjhkjhkjhk,mniu,mk,mkjh%"
```

ExampleTable.StringContains has values that look like 'someuser@example.com', 'someuser2@example.com', etc.

This doesn't match because LIKE only finds sub strings of the column value, not the other way around.  Any ideas on commands to find rows where the table value is a substring of the passed string?

Comment: have you tried having it in the order: "someuser@example.com" LIKE StringContains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the `LIKE` in the opposit order. Since you have to add those `%` you'll have to [`concatenate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) the field first:

```
SELECT *
FROM ExampleTable
WHERE "lkjlkjsomeuser@example.comjkjhkjhkjhkjhk,mniu,mk,mkjh" LIKE CONCAT('%', StringContains, '%');
```

Comment: the comment about needing to add the % symbols was helpful, I tried it without the first time, then tried it again with.  They mean match StringContains plus anything else on either side of it, so we can match the test string there.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
ExampleTable
WHERE
'lkjlkjsomeuser@example.comjkjhkjhkjhkjhk,mniu,mk,mkjh' LIKE
  CONCAT('%', StringContains, '%')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ExampleTable
WHERE  "lkjlkjsomeuser@example.comjkjhkjhkjhkjhk,mniu,mk,mkjh" LIKE
       CONCAT("%",StringContains,"%")
```

The key is to recognize that the column variable just represents a string, and the LIKE statement is always comparing two strings in the form

`"stringA" LIKE '%stringB%'`

Usually people use it to search for a "part" of a string contained in the "whole" database field string, but you can easily switch them. The only extra tool you need is the CONCAT statement, since you want the database field to be the part instead of the whole. The CONCAT statement builds a string with the %'s around the database field string, and the string form of the argument is now equivalent to

`"stringB" LIKE "%stringA%"`